# Wating for connection (netbeans-xdebug)

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I've visited several howtos and tried all of them - but still I get the dreaded 'Waiting for connection' in Netbeans. Here's a snapshot of my environment:

`$ php -i`

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.6.4-4ubuntu6

Build Date => Apr 17 2015 15:45:44
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
...

xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.3.2
IDE Key => netbeans-xdebug

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => netbeans-xdebug => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 192.168.0.5 => 192.168.0.5
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

My `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` follows:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1:81
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.5
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

`$ sudo netstat -taupen`

```
tcp   212534      0 192.168.0.5:34645       5.77.39.20:80           CLOSE_WAIT  1000       92048       19496/php
```

192.168.0.5 is my local machine

`$ telnet 192.168.0.5 9000`

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

`$ sudo ufw status`

```
Status: inactive
```

Upon hitting the Debug Project button in the IDE and back at the terminal:

`$ netstat -an | grep 9000`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

And my Netbeans config:

[image]

There is nothing in my PHP error logs. Can you deduce what I'm doing wrong or which setting I've missed with the above information?

Thanks in advance

@rocky

I dont think I'm running a firewall since from

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Anyways:

```
$ sudo iptables --list 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

which isn't amazingly user friendly?

Comment: Are you running a firewall? `iptables --list` might tell you.   I generally have iptables log errors, so you would have seen that in the logs, but I think by default logging is disabled. In general the error messages are showing that you don't have something listening on the (IPv4?) port. The only indication that you have something listing on port 9000 that it listens on a IPv6 port (not IPv4). Therefore,  the telnet invocation should be something like:  `telnet -6  ::: 9000`.

Comment: I just re-ran [my tutorial](http://programster.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/ubuntu-12-setting-up-php-xdebug-with.html) on the matter (written for 12.04 but works for 14.04 as well) and thought it wasn't working. Restarting netbeans after chrome was already open seemed to fix the issue.  Are you using xdebug helper in chrome and changed the bug icon to green after setting it to netbeans by right clicking it and selecting options (step 8 and 9)?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, work and all that. I use XDebug directly in Netbeans. This [https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#howDebuggerWorks] article describes it succinctly.  The problem for me is that the buttons in my IDE don't light-up. The whole thing just hangs with the message described in the post title.